# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file - how to see why the file is required?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I keep getting this error after switching from boost 159 to boost 155:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_59.lib`
```

I searched all project files in the solution and did not find any occurence of `1_59` string. What I need to do is to track the `.obj` or `.lib` file that is causing my project to require `libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_59.lib` instead of `libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_55.lib`.

Is there anything like dependency tree that I could observe to find source of the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you changed all the include paths to point to 1.55 properly? Seems like visual studio configuration problem.

Comment: I figured it out, there are files with `.tlog` extension. These also need to be modified.